# Zsh completion on the second command or after an alias?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I have changed my OS X Yosemite shell to Zsh and configured with "oh my zsh"  plugins, recently i installed proxychains-ng to proxy command line tools, but i found zsh completion does not work on the command after proxychains4, like

```
proxychains4 wget [hit tab], will not come up with wget's options
proxychains4 gi[tab], will not come up with "git"
```

And zsh does not work on command after alias either,

```
alias proxy="http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:12345"
proxy brew[hit tab], will not come up with brew's subcommands
```

there will be no completions for command and it's option. Any idea? thank you.

Answer (score 14):

By default, zsh expands alias before doing completion. It's possible that your configuration disables this; you can reenable it explicitly by unsetting the [`complete_aliases` option](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-COMPLETEALIASES).

```
unsetopt complete_aliases
```

For an external command like `proxychains4`, you can declare that its arguments are themselves a command and its arguments by making its completion [`_precommand`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fnormal). This isn't easy to find in the documentation, but you can observe the configuration for similar commands such as `nohup` by running `echo $_comps[nohup]`. This is with the “new” completion system (after running `compinit`).

```
compdef _precommand proxychains4
```

Answer (score 0):

well, i found one solution from the sudo plugin of "oh my zsh", here is the code modified from sudo plugin, i call it proxychains-ng-plugins.zsh, place it to $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/proxychain-ng/, and load it to ~/.zshrc, plugins=(),then source ~/.zshrc :

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Description
# -----------
#
# sudo will be inserted before the command
#
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Authors
# -------
#
# * Dongweiming <ciici123@gmail.com>
#
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

proxychains-ng-command-line() {
[[ -z $BUFFER ]] && zle up-history
[[ $BUFFER != proxychains4\ * ]] && BUFFER="proxychains4 -q $BUFFER"
zle end-of-line
}
zle -N proxychains-ng-command-line
# Defined shortcut keys: [Esc] [Esc]
bindkey "\e^" proxychains-ng-command-line
```

so type a command first, then hist ESC+CTRL, proxychains4 will be appended in the beginning.

but this is no the answer to my question.